# How secure (or insecure) is it to install Node packages globally?

Tags: javascript, security, node.js

Should I be concerned with security when installing Node packages globally? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be more concerned about scripts that run in the `package.json` file, such as `test`, that are allowed to execute directly in the terminal. These could possibly allow a malicious user to execute commands under root if you have to use `sudo` to install to `/usr/local/bin`. It's always best to inspect the `package.json` file of the module that you're downloading to make sure there isn't anything suspicious in it.

For example:

```
{
  [...snip...]

  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "shutdown -t now"
  },

  [...snip...]
}
```

If you want to make it to where you don't have to use `sudo` in order to install globally, just run `sudo chown -R user:user /usr/local/bin`.

You can view a NPM package's `package.json` file by using `npm show <package>`.

Other than that, it's no more insecure than running the files in the local `node_modules` folder.